# Increase negative score threshold for questions to get into active feed

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Questions on Stack Exchange scoring some number of downvotes are not getting into active feed. Guess there are reasons why it´s so, but the question is not about it. The problem is once your question got enough downvotes it becomes more or less invisible for the users, so even if the question gets improved it´s unlikely somebody will see the improvements. So since politics has a relative low threshold of -3 I am asking to increase it for example to -7 like on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). I personaly think that -5 would be a good new threshold, since also 5 votes are necesary to close a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll start with the bad news: I'm afraid **this simply isn't something that anyone on Politics.SE has the power to do**. This is a network-wide setting, and not something that can be changed from site to site.

If you *really* want this to be implemented, you would have to go to [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and make the case for it there. However, I doubt this request would be well-received there, as most of your points are already covered by existing network features.

> The problem is once your question got enough downvotes it becomes more or less invisible for the users

Not necessarily. I personally always use the "Recently Active Questions" tab *specifically because* it doesn't hide heavily-downvoted questions, and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

> even if the question gets improved it´s unlikely somebody will see the improvements

Again, not necessarily. As well as checking "Recently Active Questions", if you want to keep an eye on a specific question and see if it gets improved, you can follow it and you'll receive notifications if it gets edited. Again, this is something I routinely do with posts I feel are low-quality and/or liable to cause controversy.

> since politics has a relative[ly] low threshold of -3

As I said before, the threshold is a network-wide setting, not something that varies from site to site. The -3 threshold isn't "relatively low", it's the same as every other site on the network. It may *seem* low simply because Politics.SE is a magnet for highly-opinionated and/or controversial questions that end up accruing large numbers of downvotes.

---

TL;DR: We can't do this, and we probably wouldn't even if we could, because there are already methods available for users to check if a downvoted question has been edited.

Comment: Since you have mentioned Meta.SE, there is already a discusion, by which this question was inspired:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/1122383

Comment: How do you get to the tab that shows questions regardless of score?

Comment: @JoeW Click "Questions" on the left-hand menu.

Comment: "If you really want this to be implemented, you would have to go to Meta.SE and make the case for it there." Unfortunately I can´t ask it there because of question ban.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to increase the amount of bad questions that can be seen on the activity page and a score of -3 seems acceptable for hiding questions on the main site.

The score is lower on meta because there is a difference in the way voting works and down voting is also a sign of disagreement with a post or the idea in the post.

Comment: But if the question is really as bad it should be closed or deleted.

Comment: @convert That might be the case but it still doesn't belong on the front page once the score for it gets below a certain threshold which was decided as a score of -3.  And if you have a question that has a bad score you are always free to flag it and request moderators to delete it if you are unable to do it yourself.

Comment: But not every downvoted question needs to be deleted, some of them can be improved and there should be a chance to se the improvement.

Comment: The purpose of hiding those questions is to hide questions that are perceived to be bad from the home page and I see no reason why that threshold should be changed causing more bad questions to show.

Comment: Just to make it clear I have not said that the threshold should be remooved and all downvoted questions should be visible. Also I have not said that the new threshold should be -7, it can be lower.

Comment: @convert I know what you are saying and I disagree that it should be lowered. I don't see why you feel the need to argue with me and say that my opinion of your suggestion is wrong. In all honesty the more you argue with me the more I am convinced that it shouldn't change.

Comment: Because downvoted question, which are not closed, should get a chance to be improved. For closed questions I agree with you and wouldn´t even mind if the threshold get lower for closed questions.

Comment: @convert Again, I am asking why are you continuing to argue with me about my opinion, you are not going to change it. If you feel that strongly you should provide your own answer with a suggestion about what the threshold should be. There is no reason to keep trying to convince me that my opinion is wrong because you are not going to change it. I see nothing wrong with the score threshold of -3 for showing on the main page.

Comment: But I have provided in the question a threshold which I think could be fair.

Comment: @convert Can you please stop with the comments trying to argue why I am wrong for disagreeing with your suggestion. As I said before you are not going to change my mind and if you feel there is a better solution you should answer your own question and put it there.

Answer (score -1):

I would wholeheartedly agree with Joe W on questions that don't have answers, but when there are answers, things are different. Especially if there are good answers, it's really a shame that these good answers are no longer visible together with the bad question. Ideally it would be good to consider whether the bad question has good answers and then define the question's visibility in terms of the bad question's ratio to good answers.

Comment: Part of the reason for hiding them is to discourage answering bad questions as when that happens they tend to get pointed at when justifying a new question.

Comment: Of course, as long as there are no answers. But if there were answers before the question was voted down, then what?

Comment: Really good point, even I have not thought about it. Downvoted questions without answers are much easier to delete, while questions with upvoted answers should not be deleted. So would be fair to treat it similar way when hiding questions.

Comment: Just because someone answers a bad question doesn't mean that it is a good answer. Also just because it was answered before it was downvoted doesn't mean it should have been answered.

Comment: @Joe W Please don´t take it personally defenetly no offence, but why have you answered my really awful question?

Comment: @convert Voting works different on meta and a downvote is also used to show disagreement with what is being asked/suggested in a question. That isn't even counting the fact that a -1 score doesn't mean it is a really awful question.

Comment: @Joe W I was tallking about an other question, exactly this one: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79593/has-any-us-president-tried-to-reclaim-office-after-he-lost-it

Comment: @convert It wasn't downvoted that much when I answered it.

Comment: @Joe W But there are even badges for answering downvoted question if the question gets upvotes after the answer.

Comment: @convert That doesn't mean that a downvoted question should still appear on the main page.

Comment: @Joe W I know, you have made this point very clear. My coment was refering to "Part of the reason for hiding them is to discourage answering bad questions".

Comment: @convert It didn't seem to be the case as you brought this up again after so long to bring up the badges which are not relevant to the issue of hiding the question from the front page due to the low score.

Comment: @Joe W I was refering to the part about discourage answering bad questions.

Comment: @convert You mentioned the badge which is irrelevant to the decision to hide questions after they reach a score of -3. I would not have brought this up again if you had not brought something up again.